# AFNetworking POST request fails while sending html string as parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post, afnetworking

I am sending html string like

```
summary = "<p align=\"right\" style=\" \"><u><b><font face=\".SF UI Text\"  style=\" font-size:16px; color:rgb(0,0,0); \" >Paras</font></b></u></p>"
```

as POST parameters, but request fails every time.
And this request dictionary is converted by AFNetworking into json string like

```
"summary" : "<p align=\"right\" style=\" \"><u><b><font face=\".SF UI Text\"  style=\" font-size:16px; color:rgb(0,0,0); \" >Paras<\/font><\/b><\/u><\/p>"
```

I so think there may the problem, but I am not sure.
I dont know why the request fails only when I send parameters as html string.

```
[requestDict setObject:htmlString forKey:@"summary"];
```

Setting up request dictionary as above

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
            [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
            manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"accessToken"] != nil)
            {
    //                     NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"accessToken"]);
                [manager.requestSerializer setValue:requestAuthorization forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
            }

    //            NSLog(@"%@", requestAuthorization);
            [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"guest" forHTTPHeaderField:@"user_type"];
            [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
            [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"device_id"];
            [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] forHTTPHeaderField:@"device_os"];
            [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName] forHTTPHeaderField:@"device_name"];
    [manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:success failure:failure];
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `requestDict` is not used in your code. There is only `parameters`. Could you show the real code of your conversion and how `requestDict` and `parameters` are linked? Since you already set the requestSerializer to `AFJSONRequestSerializer`, `parameters` has to be a `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I have used it, I added that code just for an example and I am passing requestDict to another web service calling method into "parameters" object

Comment: With that: `parameters = @{@"summary":@"<p align=\"right\" style=\" \"><u><b><font face=\".SF UI Text\"  style=\" font-size:16px; color:rgb(0,0,0); \" >Paras</font></b></u></p>"}`, it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      NSString * htmlstring =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p align=\"right\" style=\" \"><u><b><font face=\".SF UI Text\"  style=\" font-size:16px; color:rgb(0,0,0); \" >Paras</font></b></u></p>"];

 NSString *strRequetURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url"];
        [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] setTimeoutInterval:30];
        [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] POST:strRequetURL parameters:dictParameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            completion(responseObject);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"error %@",error.description);
           // DisplayAlert(@"Network Connection Timed Out");
        }];
```

please use this code and let me know what your getting

Comment: actually, i am using html string to save formatting when I come back for editing and it is already assigned to a NSString object, please refer the sample string mentioned into question.

Comment: This is thing that I dont want to because after conversion I will lose all those html tags which are required to do formatting

Comment: without using html string you will get responds may i know

Comment: basically what I want is to save and send full html string into API so that it can be in sync with all the platforms of my app.

Comment: you can pass this string 

  NSString * htmlstring =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p align=\"right\" style=\" \"><u><b><font face=\".SF UI Text\"  style=\" font-size:16px; color:rgb(0,0,0); \" >Paras</font></b></u></p>"];

Comment: Are you using which i have added new code. please test now and let me know